# Find all background urls with regular expression in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string which has following:

```
<div style="background-image:url(some src); background-color:some color;">
   <div style="background-image:url(some src); background-color:some color;">  </div>
</div>
```

I need to find all background-image urls in this string. For now I have following regular expression:   `/background-image.*[);]/g`

But it takes background-image and background-color and it gives me just one occurrence instead of two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### RegEx Solution:

Replace your regex with this:

```
/(background-image.*?(?:;))/g
```

- `/(` Delimiter and capturing group
- `background-image` Matches the same thing in the string
- `.*?`  Matches any character *(except newline)*
- `(?:` Non-capturing group
- `;` Matches the character ; literally
- `g` *(modifier)* global. All matches *(don't return on first match)*

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uD5hQ9/6)

---

```js
var str = '<div style="background-image:url(some src); background-color:some color;">\
   <div style="background-image:url(some src); background-color:some color;">  </div>\
</div>';
var result = /(background-image.*?(?:;))/g.exec(str);
document.write(result[0]+"<br />");
document.write(result[1]);
```

---

### JQuery solution:

Selecting `style` attribute *(in other word parsing HTML codes)* and then select specific property of it *(in this case `background-image`)*

```js
var str = '<div style="background-image:url(some src); background-color:some color;">\
               <div style="background-image:url(some src); background-color:some color;">  </div>\
               </div>';

alert($('div', str).attr("style").split(';')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```